Password manager recommendations
I am looking for a password manager that:

is free
supports 2fa codes, so that it could replace an authenticator app
Syncs passwords and 2fa online (not self-hosted)
Browser/phone integration, of course


What do you mean by "supports 2FA codes"? The generation of them? Regardless, this defeats the purpose of 2FA as one layer is basically gone when someone gains access to your account.

@Destroy666 By "supports 2FA codes", I mean that I don't want to need to use a separate Authenticator app as well as a password manager. Instead, I want the authenticator app to be available as a feature in the password manager.

I use KeePassXC, I have it installed on my PC and on my phone - KeePassDX. My passwords are not something that changes very often, so I just periodically copy the updated file from my PC to my mobile device. This happens 1-3 times a year, so it doesn't cause me any trouble. I feel calmer if my passwords are not in some online service.
I don't use 2fa, so I can't say anything about this functionality

I'm using it to my Linux desktop as well and I'm going to use it on Android. I would copy it periodically as you from PC to Android, but is it available on Android or should I use another app that understands the database?

@xralf I use it https://www.keepassdx.com/

Note: you shouldn't normally use a password manager for 2FA. This eliminates one layer of security almost entirely for just a bit of comfort. 2FA then only protects you from weak passwords being leaked/cracked, but why would you use weak passwords with password manager in the 1st place?
If you still want to go for that option for whatever reason, e.g. you feel your password manager will be 100% safe or you don't care about potential breach, then bunch of popular free password managers fit your criteria.
For example, Bitwarden is a very popular option that's available on all platforms, free and supports TOTP generation and autofill.
